# Cant find Codemirror selectLines

Tags: codemirror

I want to use Codemirror's selectLines function. But I am not sure which js files its available into.

```
    selectLines(startHandle, startOffset, endHandle, endOffset);
```

Comment: it's not clear what you're asking, please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function. See the `setSelection` method instead: http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#setSelection